# Hide and unhide specific parts of excel project

Tags: vba, excel, show-hide

I just started with VBA and am currently struggling to find a solution to this problem:

I understand how hiding works and have code for hiding one range of rows/columns (Worksheets("Sheet3").Columns("A:G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True), but I wanted to be able to store a "list" of column + sheet and a list of rows + sheet. Then run the hiding code in a loop for every range in both lists.

At the moment this is what I've got (but I don't know how to make it work):

```
Sub Test()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Integer
Dim Lastrow As Long
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To Lastrow
'To hide sheets
Sheets(Cells(i, 1).Value).Visible = False
'To hide row on sheet
Rows(Cells(i, 2).Value).Hidden = True
'To hide row on specific sheet
Sheets(Cells(i, 1).Value).Rows(Cells(i, 2).Value).Hidden = True

Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: So far you have nothing in this code referring to any list at all. How about an XML file as list? You could have the sheet names as nodes and the respective columns and rows to be hidden as children of the respective sheet node. Sound OK?

Comment: I've just started with vba. How do I do that?

Comment: By learning it? There are tons of tutorials on the web. On SO we help each other understand, we don't just throw around with free coding. Code that you don't understand is always dangerous. Here's one point to start: http://www.excel-vba.com/excel-vba-solutions-beginners.htm

Comment: I did not ask for code (IJS). On the website you have given me there isn't a reference to nodes anywhere. Why did you link that website?

Comment: Because when I recommended using an XML file you said you "just started with VBA". Hence I saw no benefit in providing code to parse an XML DOM Document at this stage. Maybe this link helps you better. http://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-read-data-from-xml-file/

Comment: This helped a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Try my code from the chat. Should be a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just post my last response from chat here, please let me - and others! - know whether it helped.

1) Store the values which rows/columns are to be hidden on which sheet in an XML like this:

```
<hideme>
  <Sheets>
    <Sheet name="Sheet1">
      <rows>
        <row range="3:3"/>
        <row range="13:13"/>
      </rows>
      <columns>
        <column range="C:C"/>
        <column range="F:F"/>
      </columns>
    </Sheet>
    <Sheet name="Sheet2"/>
    <Sheet name="Sheet3">
      <rows>
        <row range="5:5"/>
      </rows>
    </Sheet>
  </Sheets>
</hideme>
```

For the macro, you need to set a reference to Microsoft XML, v6.0. (i.e. in VB Editor, Tools=>References).

```
Sub HideMe()

Dim xml As DOMDocument60
Dim xmlSheets As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim n As IXMLDOMNode, r As IXMLDOMNode, c As IXMLDOMNode, xmlRows As IXMLDOMNodeList, xmlColumns As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim ro As IXMLDOMNode, col As IXMLDOMNode, ran As String
Dim sh As Worksheet

Dim xmlpath As String

xmlpath = "[path to your xml]"

Set xml = New DOMDocument60
xml.Load (xmlpath)

Set xmlSheets = xml.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//Sheet")

For Each n In xmlSheets 'Sheet nodes
    Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(n.Attributes.getNamedItem("name").Text)
    Set r = n.SelectSingleNode("rows")
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        Set xmlRows = r.SelectNodes("row")
        For i = 0 To xmlRows.Length - 1
            ran = xmlRows.Item(i).Attributes.getNamedItem("range").Text
            sh.Rows(ran).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Next i
    End If

    Set c = n.SelectSingleNode("columns")
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        Set xmlColumns = c.SelectNodes("column")
        For i = 0 To xmlColumns.Length - 1
            ran = xmlColumns.Item(i).Attributes.getNamedItem("range").Text
            sh.Range(ran).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Next i
    End If
Next n

End Sub
```